# Using JavaScript to replace ">" text

Tags: javascript, text, greasemonkey

I'd like to do a *Greentext* plugin for Firefox using Greasemonkey,but without jQuery.

Here's what I did:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function highlight() {
        var elm = document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper");

        for(i = 0; i < elm.length; i++)
        {
            elm[i].innerHTML.replace(">","pony");
        }
    }

    alert("PONY");
</script>
</head>

<body onload="highlight()">
<div class="mainWrapper"><span class="noob"> > N00b </span>
</div>
</body>
```

This is a testing version for the function, I did it because I think that the problem was Greasemonkey, but it doesn't work yet.

Can you help me? I'm not very good at programming and I don't know how to script on JS very well.

Comment: Replacing all `>`s, even those that are supposed to be closing a tag, is a bad idea. You might even NOT replace the ones you WANT to replace, because they get escaped by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, you need to work on only the text parts of the page -- so that the HTML (and any attached JS) is not wrecked.

So (1) do not use `innerHTML`, and (2) The code would best use a technique called [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recursion/info), to efficiently parse the nodes.

Also note that ***>*** can be coded as either `>` or `&gt;` (and possibly some rarer methods too).

Here is **a complete Greasemonkey script** that does this kind of search and replace:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Replace HTML-sensitive text
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include     http://fiddle.jshell.net/DJLEq/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var targElements    = document.querySelectorAll ("div.mainWrapper");

for (var J = targElements.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    repGreaterWithPonies (targElements[J] );
}

function repGreaterWithPonies (node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // YOUR CUSTOM REPLACE GOES HERE.
        node.nodeValue  = node.nodeValue.replace (/>|&gt;/ig, "pony");
    }
    else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        for (var K = 0, numNodes = node.childNodes.length;  K < numNodes;  ++K) {
            repGreaterWithPonies (node.childNodes[K] );
        }
    }
}
```

Install that script and [you can **see it work on this page**: fiddle.jshell.net/DJLEq/...](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DJLEq/2/show/)

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work. Facebook doesn't accept HTML code in text spaces and that's why i need to use innerHTML.I must interact with HTML cache of the page.

Comment: That may be true, but that's not what the question stated or implied. The question, that was **actually asked** has been **answered.**  If that's not what you meant, start a new question and don't omit apparently key details like how this will be used with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear on the question, but looking at your code it looks like you would like to do something like:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function highlight() {
    var elm = document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper");
    for(i = 0; i < elm.length; i++)             
    {                        
      elm[i].innerText = elm[i].innerText.replace(">","pony");          
    }      
   } 
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="highlight()">
<div class="mainWrapper">><span class="noob"> N00b </span> 
</div>
</body>​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A8a2u/)**